# Server selection timed out after 30000 ms MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have configured the AWS IAM role and atlas database access for lambda but I am still getting this error
{
"errorType": "MongoServerSelectionError",
"errorMessage": "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
"trace": [
"MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms",
"    at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:291:38)",
"    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)",
"    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)"
]
}

please tell me what I am doing wrong